# How Can save JSON generated from Form Builder in the process user task?

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm creating process have usertask contain form created from **Form Builder** , How can keep this JSON in the process ?

it's should create property in extension tab, and when start process the form should be reload JSON propery value ?

there are example can me follow up ?

[Process Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4vT7.png)

[Form Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRIhT.png)

JSON generated :

```
{
components: [
{
    input: true,
    tableView: true,
    inputType: "text",
    inputMask: "",
    label: "First Name",
    key: "firstName",
    placeholder: "Enter your first name",
    prefix: "",
    suffix: "",
    multiple: false,
    defaultValue: "",
    protected: false,
    unique: false,
    persistent: true,
    validate: {
        required: false,
        minLength: "",
        maxLength: "",
        pattern: "",
        custom: "",
        customPrivate: false
    },
    conditional: {
        show: false,
        when: null,
        eq: ""
    },
    type: "textfield",
    $$hashKey: "object:14",
    autofocus: false,
    hidden: false,
    clearOnHide: true,
    spellcheck: true
},
{
    input: true,
    tableView: true,
    inputType: "text",
    inputMask: "",
    label: "Last Name",
    key: "lastName",
    placeholder: "Enter your last name",
    prefix: "",
    suffix: "",
    multiple: false,
    defaultValue: "",
    protected: false,
    unique: false,
    persistent: true,
    validate: {
        required: false,
        minLength: "",
        maxLength: "",
        pattern: "",
        custom: "",
        customPrivate: false
    },
    conditional: {
        show: false,
        when: null,
        eq: ""
    },
    type: "textfield",
    $$hashKey: "object:15",
    autofocus: false,
    hidden: false,
    clearOnHide: true,
    spellcheck: true
},
{
    type: "button",
    theme: "primary",
    disableOnInvalid: true,
    action: "submit",
    block: false,
    rightIcon: "",
    leftIcon: "",
    size: "md",
    key: "submit",
    tableView: false,
    label: "Submit",
    input: true,
    $$hashKey: "object:18",
    autofocus: false
}],
display: "form",
page: 0
```

}
        );